# How to remote login with SFTP into Docker container?

Tags: server, authentication, docker, sftp

There is a Docker container that operates as a web server (IP address: `172.20.1.24`). Also provided by the host machine (this machine runs on the docker) (IP address: `172.20.1.1`)

Every virtualhost on the server belongs to a separate user. I want to solve it with key authentication so that I can log in from the host machine as a user on the server.

OpenSSH client and server installed.

So, for example:

```
user@HOST: sftp serveruser@server <-key authentication here
```

How feasible is the easiest way? I'm still a beginner in this area.